# Hibernate updating primary key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

is it possible to update a `primary key` having more than one table **mapping**? 
How can i update **id** in **Master** table?

```
CREATE TABLE Master (id INT, name VARCHAR(20),address VARCHAR(20),Primary key(id));

CREATE TABLE Slave_1 (id INT,s1_id INT,area VARCHAR(20),project VARCHAR(20),primary key(s1_id),Foreign Key (id) references Master(id));

CREATE TABLE Slave_2 (id INT,s2_id INT,area VARCHAR(20),project VARCHAR(20),primary key(s2_id),Foreign Key (id) references Master(id));
```

Comment: A primary key is thought to be constant for the lifetime of the universe, or at least for the lifetime of the application. There should never be a reason to update the primary key of some entity!

Answer (score 0):

You could do follows:

1. Disable the foreign key constraints.
2. Update id/references
3. Enable foreign key constraints.

Comment: This would mean that you lose the referential integrity for the time of changing the ids. All other transaction occuring at the same time can then leave you in an inconsistent state and possibily you cannot reactivate the constraints after changing the ids.

Comment: @UwePlonus such change in DB is so serious that it should be done during maintenance-shutdown-time anyway, so there shouldn't be other transactions at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You cannot without changing the constraints.

This is a limitation of the database and not of hibernate.

When you change the `id` of the table `Master` the `id` columns of the slaves have no reference.

The same would be if you try to change the `id`s of the slave tables.

Also why do you try to change the primary key? This is very unusual.

Comment: I have an id that might used by different tables as a foreign key...One's i have to update the id with some other...Is there any solution

Answer (score 0):

It is very bad practice to change a primary key.

Can't you just create a new Master record, let the slaves point to the new record, and then delete the old record. That would work in Hibernate, without needing pure SQL or disabling constraints.

Comment: The only alternate solution is to use native SQL, maybe using @AdamDyga's 'on update cascade' foreign keys. But if you do any update via native SQL queries, hibernate won't know it, so you need to make sure you evict all related cached objects in 1st or 2nd level cache. If you create a new record like I suggest, all caches will be updated automatically.

Comment: As I already mentioned in the other comment, such a change is so serious that I wouldn't risk doing that on live database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, changing ID is something that nobody should normally do. But if there is any reason for that, then it cannot be done using Hibernate (ie. and mapped classes). Hibernate will not tolerate that and raise error if you try to change entity ID.

To make the change you have to use native queries. And probably the safest and easiest way to do this is to let the DB do the job for you. You only need to define **"on update cascade"** action for the foreign key columns.

```
CREATE TABLE Master (id INT, name VARCHAR(20),address VARCHAR(20),Primary key(id));

CREATE TABLE Slave_1 (id INT,s1_id INT,area VARCHAR(20),project VARCHAR(20),primary key(s1_id),Foreign Key (id) references Master(id) **on update cascade**);

CREATE TABLE Slave_2 (id INT,s2_id INT,area VARCHAR(20),project VARCHAR(20),primary key(s2_id),Foreign Key (id) references Master(id) **on update cascade**);
```

This way, whenever you change the ID column in Master table, it will be automatically cascaded to all referencing columns.